# решение для создания уведомлений для программы стороннего разработчика, в которой они не предусмотрены

Tags: windows

Например , есть программа, в неё приходят сообщения, но нет звукового оповещения или может даже и всплывающего окошка. Какое есть стороннее средство для решения этого вопроса? Первое что мне в голову приходит, это программа которая "слушает" определенную часть монитора (ту часть где появляется новое сообщение) и при изменении уведомляет об этом. 
 Или это программа , которая может слушать определенный порт на котором работает программа и сообщает, если есть активность.

Comment: > "слушает" определенную часть монитора? 

в смысле?

> может слушать определенный порт на котором работает программа и сообщает, если есть активность.
клиент-приложение может взять любой свободный порт из диапазона. А может быть и https соединение.

я вижу вариант только пропатчить программу.

Comment: как пропатчить программу, которая принадлежит какой нибудь компании.  Ну например: указывается часть монитора, если в этой части пиксели изменили свой цвет, значит есть уведомление. Комп никто не трогает, программа открыта и за работу берутся, только если есть новое сообщение. Поэтому подобный мониторинг пикселей подошел бы, только как его осуществить. Теоретически не вижу ничего невозможно.

Comment: Например делать скриншот участка монитора, и сверять с прошлым скрином. Написать для этого скрипт. возможно ли

Comment: > как пропатчить программу, которая принадлежит какой нибудь компании
реверс инженеринг. 

> указывается часть монитора, если в этой части пиксели изменили свой цвет, значит есть уведомление
а если монитор/разрешение экрана поменяли или еще что-нибудь подобное? 
такое себе :)

Comment: ну реверс инженеринг сложно, потому что  я только с андроидом могу совладать в этом деле. А вот какая разница изменили разрешение или нет. Запустил скрипт. Он начал каждые 10 сек делать скриншот и сверять его с предыдущим. Изменили разрешение, он выдаст уведомление, но мы то знаем, что это от нашей деятельности он начал уведомлять и игнорим. Основная задача, когда комп никто не трогает, чтобы программа сканировала. Можно установить чтобы комп не засыпал, не проблема.

Comment: Так в чём проблема? Вы сами предложили решение - создать программу, которая будет отлавливать нужное вам окно, по таймеру создавать скриншот и сравнивать с предыдущим. При разнице более, чем N процентов, уведомлять об этом.. Только отлавливаемая программа должна не быть минимизирована. Такую программу можно создать, причём не сильно уж сложно. Это - ответ на ваш вопрос. В остальном - пожалуйста, конкретизируйте.

Comment: В остальном: Я не пишу под виндовс. Только под андроид. Вот я и хочу подобное готовое решение. Думал существуют такие программы уже в природе. Максимум, что я могу попытаться, это установить Visual Basic на котором в школе еще писал немного и пробовать на  написать. Но это крайний случай.

Comment: и я не понял, что значит, программа должна быть не минимизирована ?

Comment: Может есть какие нибудь готовые библиотеки для сравнения двух изображений? Надо свести к минимуму тот код что будет написан мной